# Turning a custom statement into code that activates

Tags: sql, function, date, netezza

I'm working with date offsets and I'm trying to 'hack' the following date function

```
now() - interval '12 month'
```

Instead of using this I want to create a variable offset that adds months to the offset depending on the current month. I have the following SQL I've created:

```
SELECT now() ||' - interval ' || 
case when to_char(now(),'MON') in('FEB','MAY','AUG','NOV') then 0
     when to_char(now(),'MON') in('MAR','JUN','SEP','DEC') then 1
     when to_char(now(),'MON') in('JAN','APR','JUL','OCT') then 2
ELSE null END + 12 || ' month' TIME_OFFSET;
```

When I run this I get the following output.

```
TIME_OFFSET  
2019-06-21 11:15:21 - interval 13 month
```

I'm trying to get it to run that'function I've created to give me the following output

```
2018-05-21 11:15:21
```

How can I get it to return this? What do I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

Just figured this out.

Use the following:

```
select add_months(now(), (-1 * 
case when to_char(now(),'MON') in('FEB','MAY','AUG','NOV') then 2
     when to_char(now(),'MON') in('MAR','JUN','SEP','DEC') then 0
     when to_char(now(),'MON') in('JAN','APR','JUL','OCT') then 1
ELSE null END) -12);
```

Gives you :

```
ADD_MONTHS
2018-06-21 16:10:52
```